# Python script "generating" "None" values

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have been having this issue with a simple python script I'm working on for an assignment. I am to make a small script simulating a lottery, and have written this code:

```
import random

def drawNumbers(nlist, n):
    drawnlist = []

    i = 0
    while i < n:
        if i == 0:
            drawnlist.append(nlist[random.randint(0,33)])
            i+=1

        else:
            r = random.randint(0,33)
            dup = False
            for x in drawnlist:
                if x == r:
                    dup = True

            if dup == False:
                drawnlist.append(nlist[r])
                i+=1

    return drawnlist

def compList(drawlist, guesslist):
    count = 0

    for j in drawlist:
        for h in guesslist:
            if j == h:
                count +=1

    return count

def winnings(right, altright):
    altcorrect = False

    if altright > 0:
        altcorrect = True

    if right == 7:
        return 2749455

    elif right == 6:
        if altcorrect:
            return 102110
        else:
            return 3385

    elif right == 5:
        return 95

    elif right == 4:
        if altcorrect:
            return 45

    else:
        return 0



a=0
tot = 0
while a <100:
    numbers = []
    i = 1
    while i <= 34:
        numbers.append(i)
        i+=1

    myGuess = []

    i = 0
    while i <7:
        if i == 0:
            myGuess.append(random.randint(1,34))
            i+=1


        else:
            r = random.randint(1,34)
            dup = False
            for x in myGuess:
                if x == r:
                    dup = True

            if dup == False:
                myGuess.append(r)
                i+=1    

    tot += winnings(compList(drawNumbers(numbers,7),myGuess),compList(drawNumbers(numbers,3),myGuess))

    a+=1

print(tot)
```

And it seems to be working fine for one iteration, however, when I increase `a` like now with a value of 100, I get an error saying that I cannot sum an "`int`" object and a "`None`" objects. When I tinkered with the code and printed "winnings" instead of the summed total for each iteration, it looks like the function sometimes returns "None" instead of a number. I can however not seem to recreate that with a smaller amount of iterations, so my question: Is this code related, or might it be that by calling the functions "too fast" it does not create a number? I know this question might seem odd, but I am new to programming as a whole and python itself, and I have no clue how to debug this.

Comment: What's the full error with trace?

Comment: The function can return `None` in this case: `elif right == 4: if altcorrect: return 45` (no `else` to the inner `if`).

Comment: `winnings(4,-1)` returns None. Is this intentional?

Comment: the "winnings" function is passed to positive integers, so altright = 1 is not a consern. Adding an `else` statement to the `elif right == 4: if altcorrect: return 45` solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `winnings` function can return `None` as there is no `else` to the inner `if`. In this case, it does not trigger the final `else` and returns `None` by default. To fix it, add an `else` to the `if`, or just remove the final `else` in `winnings`:

```
def winnings(right, altright):
    altcorrect = False
    # ...
    elif right == 4:
        if altcorrect:
            return 45
        # maybe add an else here?

    # or if you get to this point, _always_ return 0
    return 0
```

Comment: Adding an `else` to the inner if solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your winnings function sometimes returns None. It's because it's not catching some cases. Python returns None if it reaches the end of a function without any other returns being hit.

Specifically, if right is 4 and altright is 0, none of the if cases will get caught and the function returns `None`.